# Can I apply display: flex to a parent and not to a specific child?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

the div with `header` class has a `display:flex` property. I want the flex property to be applied only for the links without affecting the "nonflex" div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
 <title>return</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
 <a href="#">Accueil</a>
 <a href="#">Statistiques</a>
 <a href="#">SMS</a>
 <a href="#">mise a jour</a>
 <a href="#">Parametres</a>
 <div class="nonflex">
  
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using `ExternalInterface.call("document.getElementsByClassName('nonflex').length")`

Comment: using javascript ?

Comment: Can you clarify ? what result do you expect from the nonflex div ? fill the space left, go under and be full width or something else ? what about the links ? stay there, use full width, spray evenly , else ... glop ?

Comment: exactly , i want it to go under the links list  . i mean nonflex does not obey to the flex property as the other childs that's it .

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set the wrap propertie to the flex element and set width to 100% to the `.nonflex` child, which still be a flex-child. But Not as obvious then.

```css
.header {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 /* demo ? */
 justify-content:space-around;
  }
.header .nonflex {
  width:100%;
  /* see me for the demo*/
  padding:1em;
  border:solid;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
 <title>return</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
 <a href="#">Accueil</a>
 <a href="#">Statistiques</a>
 <a href="#">SMS</a>
 <a href="#">mise a jour</a>
 <a href="#">Parametres</a>
 <div class="nonflex">
  
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From your answer it looks like I might have misunderstood the question. I thought he doesn't want the `.nonflex` to grow, not that he wants them on another row. OP never mentioned that...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu he did clarify in reply to my comment ;)

Comment: Right. just saw it. Well, it's good you asked. A Happy New Year!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu idem, take care on the roads and of your friends, have good times :